# Simple counter in IO

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, io

I'm trying to create a simple counter which increases by 1 indefinitely, using IO.

I've been scratching my head ever since...

Ideally, I would like to do something along the lines of

```
tick = do putStr (counter)
          counter + 1
    where counter = 0
```

Then repeat the process. Then repeat the first 2 expressions. Or something along the lines of:

```
tick = tick'
       where 
           counter = 1
           tick' counter | counter > 0 = do putStrLn (show counter)
                                            tick' (counter + 1)
                         | otherwise = tick
```

Which gives me errors :/

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this *without* using a mutable cell.  You already did it with your second attempt, there's just a little error.  You need to pass an initial value to the `tick'` function, not "set it" (haskell does not have an idea of assigning variables -- only definitions.  If the line `x = y` appears, `x` will be `y` for its entire lifetime).

```
tick = tick' 0
    where ...
```

The `counter = 0` line is not doing anything; it is defining a name that is never used.  The `counter` used in the `tick'` function is bound as one of its arguments (and shadows the one defined to be 0).   Take some time to stare at it with that in mind, see if that makes sense.

There is a nice "higher order" way we can do this too.  Essentially we want to run the infinitely long block of code:

```
do
    print 0
    print 1
    print 2
    ...
```

There is a function called `sequence :: [IO a] -> IO [a]` (see caveat below) that will take a list of actions and construct an action.  So if we can construct the list `[print 0, print 1, print 2, ...]` then we can pass it to `sequence` to build the infinitely long block we are looking for.

Take note here, this is a very important concept in Haskell: `[print 0, print 1, print 2]` does not print those three numbers then construct the list `[0,1,2]`.  Instead it is itself a list of *actions*, whose type is `[IO ()]`.  Making the list does nothing; it is only when you bind an action to `main` that it will be executed.  For example, we might say:

```
main = do
    let xs = [putStrLn "hello", getLine >> putStrLn "world"]
    xs !! 0
    xs !! 0
    xs !! 1
    xs !! 1
    xs !! 0
```

This would twice print `hello`, twice get a line and print `world` after each, then once print `hello` again.

With that concept, it is easy to build the list of actions `[print 0, print 1, ...]` with a list comprehension:

```
main = sequence [ print x | x <- [0..] ]
```

We can simplify a bit:

```
main = sequence (map (\x -> print x) [0..])
main = sequence (map print [0..])
```

So `map print [0..]` is the list of actions `[print 0, print 1, ...]` we were looking for, then we just pass that to `sequence` which chains them together.

This pattern of `sequence` is common, and has its own `mapM`:

```
mapM :: (a -> IO b) -> [a] -> IO [b]
mapM f xs = sequence (map f xs)
```

Thus:

```
main = mapM print [0..]
```

About as simple as you could want.

One note about performance: since we are not using the output of these functions, we should be using `sequence_` and `mapM_`, with trailing underscores, which are optimized for that purpose.  Usually this wouldn't matter in a Haskell program because of garbage collection, but in this particular use case is kind of a special case because of various subtleties.  You'll find that without the `_`s, the memory usage of your program gradually grows as the list of results (in this case `[(),(),(),...]`) is constructed but never used.

*Caveat*: I have given the type signatures of `sequence` and `mapM` specialized to `IO`, not a general monad, so that the reader does not have to learn about the orthogonal concepts of actions having types and typeclasses at the same time.

Comment: I answered a fundamentally different question than you did.  So far as I know, there's no way to do what I did, creating a single IO action that outputs something different each time it's used, without using a mutable cell.

Comment: @Carl: Here's one `getStr >>= putStrLn` :)

Comment: @rampion Ok, clearly I should have said "tracking internal state".

Comment: I like this solution, using higher order functions to gradually solve the problem. I've had difficulties understanding what the function sequence really did, you're explanation makes it a lot clearer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Well, let's go back to basics.  What you want appears to be an IO action that when bound, prints and increments a counter?  I'm going to work from that assumption.

The first thing you need is some mutable cell, since you're using the same action each time.  It needs to have something mutable inside it to do something different each time it's used.  I'd go with an `IORef` for this case.

But keeping that `IORef` hidden is a bit tricky.  Especially since globals are bad.  The best way to do it is create the IO action from inside another IO action, and then close over the `IORef`.  Doing so gives you something like this:

```
import Data.IORef

mkCounter :: IO (IO ())
mkCounter = do
    ref <- newIORef 0
    return $ do
        counter <- readIORef ref
        print counter
        writeIORef ref $ counter + 1
```

This can be used by doing something like this:

```
main = do
    tick <- mkCounter
    tick
    tick
    tick
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second implementation is really close!

```
tick = tick'
       where 
           counter = 1
           tick' counter | counter > 0 = do putStrLn (show counter)
                                            tick' (counter + 1)
                         | otherwise = tick
```

Let's look at the errors for this:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO b0' with actual type `a0 -> IO b0'
    In the expression: tick'
```

Let's add some types to make sure we're getting what we want.

`tick` is an IO action.  We don't care what value the action encapsulates, since the whole
point of it is to run forever.

```
tick :: IO a
```

Now our error is:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO a' with actual type `a0 -> IO b0'
    In the expression: tick'
```

Well, that's pretty much the same, no help there.  Let's keep going.

`tick'` is a function that takes some integer and returns an IO action
that prints the integer and repeats `tick'` on the next value.  Again, we don't care what
value the action encapsulates, since it runs forever.

```
tick' :: Int -> IO b
```

Wait, now that error makes sense!  We defined `tick = tick'`, but the two things have fundamentally different types.  One is an action (`tick`) one is a function that returns an action (`tick'`).  All we need to do is give `tick'` some value to get the action, so let's do that.

You'd tried to do that by saying `where counter = 1` but all that did is define `counter` as 1 within the statement `tick = tick'`, and since `counter` isn't mentioned there, it wasn't used.

When you said `tick' counter | ... =`, you weren't referring to the same `counter` as on the line above.  There, you were defining another variable called `counter` that was only in scope within the definition of `tick'`.

So now our code looks like:

```
tick :: IO a
tick = tick' 1
       where 
           tick' :: Int -> IO b
           tick' counter | counter > 0 = do putStrLn (show counter)
                                            tick' (counter + 1)
                         | otherwise = tick
```

If we try to compile it, `ghc` doesn't complain, and if we try it out in `ghci` it runs as desired:

```
% ghci
ghci> :l Tick.hs
Ok, modules loaded: Tick.
ghci> tick
1
2
3
...
25244
^C
Interrupted
ghci>
```

Comment: Can't believe I was that close. Thanks for explaining the type error.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple infinite counter just use recursion:

```
counter n = do print n
               counter (n+1)

main = counter 1
```

Yet another way to implement `tick` functionality without using mutable state is to mix `State` and `IO` monad using monad transformers:

```
import Control.Monad.State

type Ticking a = StateT Int IO a

tick :: Ticking ()
tick = do
     modify succ
     get >>= liftIO . print

getCounterValue :: Ticking Int
getCounterValue = get
```

Then you can use it to create 'ticking' `IO` functions (with nuisance: `IO` functions here need to be prefixed with `liftIO` since it is now `Ticking a` monad not `IO a`):

```
ticking :: Ticking ()
ticking = do
        liftIO $ putStrLn "Starting"
        tick
        tick
        c <- getCounterValue
        liftIO $ do
            putStrLn ("Finished at " ++ show c)
            putStrLn "Press any Enter to start infinite counter"
            getChar
        forever tick
```

Which can be converted into 'normal' `IO` using `runStateT` (with initial counter value):

```
startTicking :: Ticking a -> Int -> IO a
startTicking = evalStateT
```

So:

```
main :: IO ()
main = startTicking ticking 0
```

Answer (score 0):

A forkIO safe version similar to Carl's answer using STM is

```
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import Control.Monad (replicateM_)
import Control.Monad(forever)

makeCounter :: IO (IO Int)
makeCounter = do
  var <- newTVarIO 0
  return $ do
      atomically $ do
          value <- readTVar var
          modifyTVar var (+1)
          readTVar var

-- a version that only counts from 1 to 10
main1:: IO ()
main1 = do
  counter <- makeCounter
  replicateM_ 10 $ counter >>= print


-- a version that counters forever
main2 :: IO ()
main2 = do
  counter <- makeCounter
  forever $ do
      x<- counter
      print x

main :: IO ()
main = do
  counter <- makeCounter
  tick<- counter
  tick<- counter
  print tick  -- 2
```

Reference:

1. [Mutable closures in Haskell and nested IO](https://bitemyapp.com/blog/when-nested-io-actions-are-wanted/)
2. [An EXERCISE from STM tutorial](https://www.fpcomplete.com/haskell/library/stm/)
3. [Mutable State in Haskell](https://blog.jakuba.net/2014-07-20-mutable-state-in-haskell/)